# SQL Server stored procedure needs some work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables `Product` and `Purchase`:

`Product` table:

```
ProductID = 1 
PName    = tv  
StockQty = 10
```

`Purchase` table:

```
PurchaseID = 1
PID = 1
PurchaseQty = 5
```

`Product ID` is a foreign key in `Purchase` table. I am trying to write a stored procedure so that whenever `Purchase Quantity` is added in `Purchase` table, the main table `Product` should also be changed.

For example: I add purchase quantity 5. When I refresh the `Product` table, it should display 15. With my current stored procedure, it is updating all products and increases `StockQty` by 5 - instead it should do this to only the `product id` I chose. Please advise.

Below is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertpurchase
    @PID int,
    @PurchaseQty int,
    @StockQty int
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Purchase] (PID, PurchaseQty) 
    VALUES (@PID, @PurchaseQty)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Product]  
    SET Product.StockQty = Product.StockQty  + Purchase.PurchaseQty
    FROM Purchase
END
```

Can somebody guide what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add where clause while updating.

```
'CREATE PROCEDURE 
insertpurchase
@PID int ,
@PurchaseQty int,
@StockQty int


AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Purchase] (PID ,PurchaseQty ) VALUES (@PID ,@PurchaseQty )


BEGIN

UPDATE [dbo].[Product]  
SET Product.StockQty = Product.StockQty  + @PurchaseQty
WHERE ProductID = @PID

 END '
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s true that the stored procedure needs the filter for the ProductID on the update statement. however, to make sure both update and insert are executed properly, I made some adjustment to the code with the following
1.) I removed  @StockQty because in that scenario it seems that the stored procedure only require the id of puchases item and purchase quantity
2.) I add the Transaction to make sure that both insert and update are executed properly, without it, it is possible to insert but does not update.

CREATE PROCEDURE insertpurchase
    @PID int,
    @PurchaseQty int
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Purchase] (PID, PurchaseQty) 
    VALUES (@PID, @PurchaseQty)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Product]
    SET Product.StockQty = Product.StockQty  + @PurchaseQty
    FROM Purchase
    WHERE ProductID = @PID
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END